# One of many SSIS packages fails with ConnectionManager error code 0xC0202009

Tags: ssis

There are approximately 80 packages all being executed from the main package and each copies a table from source to destination. All packages receive the same list of parameters from the main. Protection level is SaveSenitiveWithUserKey. One of the 80 packages fails with 0xC0202009. All others execute with no errors.

Before I go to the length of changing every package's protection level as is suggested by a google of the error message, I'd like to understand why one package out of 80 fails when they all appear to be identical with the exception of which table they affect.

Comment: this error not give match info, better if you show SSIS package OUTPUT window info when that package fails, there should be more specific info about error...

Comment: I ended up dropping the connection manager and adding a new one. the parameters didn't change but it started working. weirdness.